# Datasets in Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
Dataset<Tweet> ds = sc.read().json("path").as(Encoders.bean(Tweet.class));
ds.show();
JavaRDD<Tweet> dstry = ds.toJavaRDD();
System.out.println(dstry.first().getClass());
```

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 50, Column 16: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 50, Column 16: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String"; candidates are: "public void sparkSQL.Tweet.setId(long)"
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2410)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2380)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4004)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4874)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.compile(CodeGenerator.scala:1369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateSafeProjection$.create(GenerateSafeProjection.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:1325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:1322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.DeserializeToObjectExec$$anonfun$2.apply(objects.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.DeserializeToObjectExec$$anonfun$2.apply(objects.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:818)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:818)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 50, Column 16: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 50, Column 16: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String"; candidates are: "public void sparkSQL.Tweet.setId(long)"
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1497)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1494)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
```

When I looked closely the only thing I raised my doubts is this:

> No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String"; candidates are: "public void sparkSQL.Tweet.setId(long)"

Comment: Tweets defination :- Its a  class with getters and setters having long id,String name,String text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user9718686 wrote, you have different types for the id field: `String` in your json file, and `long` in your class definition. When you read it into `Dataset<Row>`, then Spark infers the schema from the file and detects that the id is of type `String` and that is why it worked when you tried to print it (as you asked for this in one of your comments). If you want to have the dataframe as `Dataset<Tweet>`, then you have to change your json files to use `long` ids instead of `String` or you can let Spark cast this id when you try to perform any [action operation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) on your dataframe.

```
Dataset<Row> rowDataset = sc.read().json("path");
Dataset<Tweet> tweetDataset = rowDataset
                .withColumn("id", rowDataset.col("id").cast(DataTypes.LongType))
                .as(Encoders.bean(Tweet.class));
tweetDataset.printSchema();
System.out.println(tweetDataset.head().getId());
```

Comment: finally i understood it,Yaay

Answer (score 2):

It gives you an error because of type mismatch:

- `Tweet` class defines `id` field as `Long`.
- Your data has `id` as `String`.

You have to either cast input or adjust class definition.

Comment: Yeah it worked, i changed the class definition and then typecasted it but why did it worked with dataframes
the code of dataframe:-

Dataset<Row> df = sc.read().json(path);


JavaRDD<String> dftry= df.javaRDD().map(s->s.toString()); 


System.out.println(dftry.take(2));

Comment: Can anyone answer me ?